# Covariant Derivative and Leibniz's Rule

Tags: differential-geometry

I was wondering if someone could help me with this section of my textbook involving the covariant derivative.

"The covariant derivative along a vector obeys the Leibniz rule with respect to the tensor product $\otimes$: for any $\vec{v}$ and any pair of tensor fields $(A,B)$:
$$\nabla_{\vec{v}}(A\otimes B) = \nabla_{\vec{v}}A\otimes B + A\otimes\nabla_{\vec{v}}B$$

This property follows easily from the definition (14.6) of the tensor product and the Leibniz rule regarding the multiplication in R."

Where $(14.6)$ is:
"
Given a tensor A of type $(k,l)$ and a tensor B of type $(m,n)$ one calls tensor product
of A by B, the tensor of type $(k + m, l + n)$ denoted by $A \otimes B$ and defined by:
$$E^{*} \times \dots \times E^{*} \times E \times \dots \times E \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$$
$$(\omega_{1}, \dots , \omega_{k+m},\vec{v_{1}}, \dots ,\vec{v_{l+n}}) \mapsto A(\omega_{1}, \dots , \omega_{k},\vec{v_{1}}, \dots ,\vec{v_{l}}) \times B(\omega_{k+1}, \dots , \omega_{k+m},\vec{v_{l+1}}, \dots ,\vec{v_{l+n}})$$

where $\times$ is multiplication within $\mathbb{R}$."

I am failing do see how it follows and I am probably missing something obviously. Secondly, I was wondering why the Leibniz rule holds for multiplication in $\mathbb{R}$. Thank you in advance.

Edit:
My definition of the covariant derivative:
If $T$ is a tensor field of type $(k,l)$, its covariant derivative $\nabla T$ is a tensor field of type $(k,l+1)$ such that the variation of $T$ between two infinitely close points $M$ and $M^{'}$ is given by
$$dT := T(M^{'}) - T(M) = \nabla_{d\vec{x}}T$$ where  $$d\vec{x} := \vec{MM'}$$ and the notation $\nabla_{d\vec{x}}T$ means that the vector $d\vec{x}$ is the last argument of the tensor $\nabla T$:
$$\forall \vec{v} \in E, \nabla_{\vec{v}} T := \nabla T(.,...,\vec{v})$$

Comment: What is your definition of $\nabla$?

Comment: I have added an edit with my definition

Comment: In most case, your equality you have question with are taken as the definition. And your definition of covariant derivatives is so imprecise that it
 is impractical if not wrong.

Comment: [Similar question on Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/492531/44126).